# Flutter audio slider with assets_audio_player

Tags: flutter, audio, slider

I'm trying to create a slider to watch the audio progress and seek some parts of the audio. In order to play local audio files I'm using the [`assets_audio_player`](https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player) package. This is my code:

```
import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';

...
...

final AssetsAudioPlayer _assetsAudioPlayer = AssetsAudioPlayer();

...
...

StreamBuilder<Duration>(
stream: _assetsAudioPlayer.currentPosition,
builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot <Duration> snapshot) {

final Duration _currentDuration = snapshot.data;
final int _milliseconds = _currentDuration.inMilliseconds;
final int _songDurationInMilliseconds = snapshot.data.inMilliseconds;

return Slider(
    min: 0,
    max: _songDurationInMilliseconds.toDouble(),
    value: _songDurationInMilliseconds > _milliseconds
            ? _milliseconds.toDouble()
            : _songDurationInMilliseconds.toDouble(),
    onChanged: (double value) {
    _assetsAudioPlayer.seek(Duration(milliseconds: (value / 1000.0).toInt()));
    },
    activeColor: Colors.blue,
    inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
  );
},
),
```

However, the behaviour of the slider is far away from the expected. I can't seek and it doesn't move. How to solve this?

Comment: if you don't mind Could you share the Github link of your project please?

Comment: May you paste you minor changes to complete this?:-)

Comment: @StanleyD I posted an answer with the code I used but it might be outdated. I've seen that [https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player](https://pub.dev/packages/assets_audio_player) contains some screenshots with sliders. When I started this project the sample app consisted only on two or three buttons, so if the author of the plugin posted that working app you should use it instead of my example

Comment: @user11908262 See my answer below. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use https://github.com/samupra/local_flutter_audio_player 
It has all features you need

code snippet

```
Widget slider() {
    return Slider(
        value: _position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
        min: 0.0,
        max: _duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
        onChanged: (double value) {
          setState(() {
            seekToSecond(value.toInt());
            value = value;
          });});
  }

  Widget localAsset() {
    return _tab([
      Text('Play Local Asset \'audio.mp3\':'),
      _btn('Play', () => audioCache.play('audio.mp3')),
      _btn('Pause',() => advancedPlayer.pause()),
      _btn('Stop', () => advancedPlayer.stop()),
      slider()
    ]);
  }
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef void OnError(Exception exception);

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new ExampleApp()));
}

class ExampleApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ExampleAppState createState() => new _ExampleAppState();
}

class _ExampleAppState extends State<ExampleApp> {
  Duration _duration = new Duration();
  Duration _position = new Duration();
  AudioPlayer advancedPlayer;
  AudioCache audioCache;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    initPlayer();
  }

  void initPlayer(){
    advancedPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
    audioCache = new AudioCache(fixedPlayer: advancedPlayer);

    advancedPlayer.durationHandler = (d) => setState(() {
      _duration = d;
    });

    advancedPlayer.positionHandler = (p) => setState(() {
    _position = p;
    });
  }

  String localFilePath;

  Widget _tab(List<Widget> children) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: children
              .map((w) => Container(child: w, padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0)))
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _btn(String txt, VoidCallback onPressed) {
    return ButtonTheme(
        minWidth: 48.0,
        child: RaisedButton(child: Text(txt), onPressed: onPressed));
  }

  Widget slider() {
    return Slider(
        value: _position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
        min: 0.0,
        max: _duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
        onChanged: (double value) {
          setState(() {
            seekToSecond(value.toInt());
            value = value;
          });});
  }

  Widget localAsset() {
    return _tab([
      Text('Play Local Asset \'audio.mp3\':'),
      _btn('Play', () => audioCache.play('audio.mp3')),
      _btn('Pause',() => advancedPlayer.pause()),
      _btn('Stop', () => advancedPlayer.stop()),
      slider()
    ]);
  }

  void seekToSecond(int second){
    Duration newDuration = Duration(seconds: second);

    advancedPlayer.seek(newDuration);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 1,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'Local Asset'),
            ],
          ),
          title: Text('audioplayers Example'),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [localAsset()],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I was able to solve my problem with this example, I just had to do some minor changes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I abandoned this project over a year ago, but this is the code I used to make it work. I don't remember too much details about it, but hope it helps:

```
                    _selectedIndex == index && (songDuration > 10000.0)// && playing == true
                                            ? Row(
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Flexible(
                                              flex: 2,
                                              child: Container(
                                                width: double.infinity,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Flexible(
                                              flex: 14,
                                              child: StreamBuilder<Duration>(
                                                stream: _assetsAudioPlayer.currentPosition,
                                                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Duration> snapshot) {
                                                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                                    return Slider(
                                                      value: 0.0,
                                                      onChanged: (double value) => null,
                                                      activeColor: Colors.transparent,
                                                      inactiveColor: Colors.transparent,
                                                    );
                                                  }

                                                  final PlayingAudio playing2 = _assetsAudioPlayer.current.value;
                                                  final Duration position = snapshot.data;
                                                  // bool _finish = _assetsAudioPlayer.finished.value;

                                                  // print(playing2);

                                                  return Slider(
                                                    min: 0.0,
                                                    max: playing2.duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble() - 0.01,
                                                    value: position.inMilliseconds.toDouble() == playing2.duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble()
                                                        ? 0.0
                                                        : position.inMilliseconds.toDouble(),
                                                    onChanged: (double value) {
                                                      _assetsAudioPlayer.seek(Duration(milliseconds: value.toInt()));
                                                      value = value;
                                                    },
                                                    onChangeEnd: (double value) {
                                                    },
                                                    activeColor: Colors.blue,
                                                    inactiveColor: Color(0xFFCEE3EE),
                                                  );
                                                },
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ) : Container(),
```

Comment: Thanks man. You saved my bacon. This library is good but very poorly documented. From you answer I still had to wriggle around a bit. I'm still unsure how to reset the slider and progress text